# Can Trinity be taught only from Bible?

Tags: biblical-basis, trinity, literalism

Is it possible to teach the concept of Trinity directly from the words of Bible (or sayings of Jesus), without any interpretation or explanation?

Here interpretation or explanation excludes literal meaning in any language. So, no interpretation/explanation means only with the words of bible or it's literal meaning is to be used. And I am not asking for biblical basis of Trinity. Hope this is clear now.

Comment: Even if I just give you mnay citation, it will be the explanation/interpretation anyway.

Comment: This question is based on a logical fallacy and miss-understanding about what "interpretation" is in general. You might as well ask "without reading" as say "without any interpretation". Letters on a page only mean something if you have a framework for interpreting them and that includes language and context. The only reasonable way to answer this would be to explain the basics of what "interpretation" is. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Just for clarity, here "interpretation" means "explanation in a certain way", which is the natural meaning.
And this question is not a duplicate of "Biblical basis for the doctrine of Trinity."

Comment: @caleb I don't think it's a duplicate either, "Biblical Basis" is asking for the Biblical Basis, this is a yes or no question.  I think (hope) there is a Biblical Basis for the Trinity, it's not the only interpretation, it is the only _valid_ interpretation and the answer to this question is why.

Comment: Absolutely a duplicate. It's not physically possible to read the Bible "without interpretation or explanation". All language must be interpreted, unless you say "here are some symbols that may or may not have meaning".

Comment: @Gulshan: "natural meaning" is a pretty arbitrary (and therefore meaningless) standard to use when interpreting any language. Ask any linguist. Words carry meaning by common consensus, and that consensus changes (over time, by region, by context, etc).

Comment: @Caleb. You cannot be a player and a referee. Limit your comments to the reason for placing a question on hold. In this case 'duplication'. Is this question a duplication of another question. If you think so then state your reasons. What does 'duplication' have to do with 'interpretation'. Why start another debate?

Comment: @gideon marx: Actually, on Stack Exchange [everyone is both player and referee](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/stack-overflow-is-you/). It's like golf.  I _think_ Caleb is trying to help you [edit] your question so that it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The best verse that mentions the Trinity is

> Therefore go and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the
>   name of the **Father** and of the **Son** and of the **Holy Spirit**.
>   *(Matthew 28:19, NIV)*

The best verse for the oneness of the Father and Son is

> I and the Father are **one**. *(John 10:30, NIV)*

Another verse which attests that God is one.

> "The most important one," answered Jesus, "is this: 'Hear, O Israel:
>   The Lord our God, the **Lord is one**. *(Mark 12:29, NIV)*

In addition, in the Old Testament, when God visited Abraham, he saw three persons.

> The Lord appeared to Abraham near the large trees of Mamre. Abraham
>   was sitting at the entrance to his tent. It was the hottest time of
>   the day. Abraham looked up and saw **three men** standing nearby. He
>   quickly left the entrance to his tent to meet them. He bowed low to
>   the ground. *(Genesis 18:1-2, NIV)*

Now, if you still think that these verses do not expound the concept of Trinity, it only means that you have your own way of interpretation which is not in agreement with the traditional interpretation of mainstream Christians.

Comment: "...means that you have your own way of interpretation which is not in agreement..." - absolutely.  However one must agree that it takes as much imaginative interpretation to believe those passages are connected as to believe they are distinct.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think the Doctrine of the Trinity has ever been explained as a natural phenomenon after reading the Bible.  There are places where all three Persons of the Trinity are mentioned together, like the great commission

> Go therefore, Baptizing in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit
>
> Jesus

and there's other places where Our Lord mentions only Him and the Father being one.

> I am in the father and the Father is in Me
>
> no one knows the Father like the Son
>
> IBID.

I don't know if it is right to interpret that that means Jesus knows the Father in a way not even the Holy Spirit can know Him.

Finally, there is a question of who sent who.

> ... the Father who sent me.
>
> Behold, I am sending the Paraclete (Holy Spirit)
>
> IBID.

who sent who is very important to the doctrine of the trinity, but it never got anyone in hot water until 600 years after the doctrine was formalized and accepted by most Christians as it continues to be today.

So, the Church finished the Bible in the 4th Century and 200 years later finalized the Doctrine of the Trinity at the [council of Chalcedon](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_Chalcedon) numerous other ways of coming up with interpretations of Gods nature were quashed there and one Universal interpretation was applied to everyone who wanted to be in good standing with the church.

Some people didn't get the memo and some people killed the memo bringers and some memos were so badly scorched in the desert that by the time they got it 200 years later, they called it Islam. But, no the Trinity is not reasonable and its not inherently Biblical. It takes Faith in the Church to believe in the Trinity.